# Maven Resource Filtering does not work on annotations

Tags: maven

The following is a DynamoDBTable annotation.

```
@DynamoDBTable(tableName = "customer")
public class CustomerEntity{
```

What i am trying to do is, to apply Maven Resource filtering on the tableName annotation. However, it doesn't seem to work with annotation.

```
@DynamoDBTable(tableName = "${tableName}")
public class BigNoOfCustomerLinesEntity {
```

Just to test that my Maven configuration works on the rest of the file, and it does.

```
@DynamoDBTable(tableName = "${tableName}")
public class BigNoOfCustomerLinesEntity {
   private String name = "${tableName}";
}
```

Results in:

```
@DynamoDBTable(tableName = "${tableName}")
public class BigNoOfCustomerLinesEntity {
   private String name = "customer";
}
```

Note: As i am tempted not to use annotation, and apply resource filtering on *.xml instead of java source files, i think XML based descriptor is not yet support by DynamoDB now.

Comment: Show your full pom file and an full example of your file you are trying to filer and where these files are located.

Answer (score 0):

XML based descriptor is indeed not currently supported by the DynamoDB mapper.  I'd suggest to open a github issue for this feature request at https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-java/issues.

Comment: Thanks Hanson. Perhaps i look at raising such feature request. Let you know again.